# Python Selenium Search By Attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is how I find forms in a web-page using selmium:

```
driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//form")
```

How can I edit my code to return only visible forms and those which are not disabled?

Comment: if they not `disabled` then do you see `enabled` tag in HTMLDOM  for those forms?

Comment: @cruisepandey no, and this isn't related to my question...

Answer (score -1):

To locate the ***visible*** forms which are not ***disabled*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form:not(disabled)")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//form and not(disabled)")))
  ```